# Getting colorPrimary in xml

Tags: android, styles

I have a style:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/ButtonStyle</item>
</style>
```

and in background of Button I have a shape:

```
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="?attr/colorPrimary" />
        <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#ff0000" />
        <corners android:bottomLeftRadius="5dp" android:bottomRightRadius="15dp" android:topLeftRadius="15dp" android:topRightRadius="5dp" />
    </shape>
```

In this shape I use colorPrimary. But after running this error occurred:

```
 Error inflating class Button
```

Comment: ?attr/colorPrimary can be used in drawables for api>=21

Comment: in my app minSdk is 17.

Comment: Then you cant use it. Create drawable at runtime by getting primarycolor

Comment: try `@color/colorPrimary`

Answer (score 0):

You can't reference an `attribute` in an xml drawable below API 21.

Try to replace

```
    <solid android:color="?attr/colorPrimary" />
```

with

```
    <solid android:color="@color/colorPrimary" />
```

Comment: I have 2 themes and each theme has its own colorPrimary

Comment: Then change the drawable xml color programatically